# Trying to access another field when declaring associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

Let's say I have this:

```
$data = [
'total' => $itemNull ? 0 : $issueData['workedHours'] * $itemFound->sale_price,
'tax' => $taxRate * $data['total'], 
];
```

That line throws `undefined` and I understand the reason, since `$data` it is not fully build I cannot access it. So here is the question, is there any way to access the `'total'` field??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or define it first

```
$total = $itemNull ? 0 : $issueData['workedHours'] *$itemFound->sale_price;

$data = [
'total' => $total,
'tax' => $taxRate * $total, 
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, define it later.

```
$data = [
    'total' => $itemNull ? 0 : $issueData['workedHours'] *$itemFound->sale_price,
];

$data['tax'] = $taxRate * $data['total'];
```